# How do I recover from failure when uploading multiple files via my server to S3?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3, busboy

New to NodeJS and S3, I wrote the following exploratory code to upload files to S3 via my NodeJS server without saving the file to disk or memory:

```
var express = require('express');
var Busboy = require('busboy');
var S3 = require('../utils/s3Util');
var router = express.Router(); // mounted at /uploads

router.post("/", function (req, res, next) {
    let bb = new Busboy({ headers: req.headers });
    const uploads = [];
    bb.on('file', (fieldname, stream, filename, encoding, mimeType) => {
        console.log(`Uploaded fieldname: ${fieldname}; filename: ${filename}, mimeType: ${mimeType}`);
        uploads.push(S3.svc.upload({ Bucket: 'my-test-bucket', Key: filename, Body: stream }).promise());
    });
    bb.on('finish', () => {
        console.log("# of promises:", uploads.length);
        Promise.all(uploads).then(retVals => {
            for (let i = 0; retVals && i < retVals.length; i++) {
                console.log(`File ${i + 1}::`, retVals[i]); 
            }
            res.end();
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log("Error::", err);
            res.status(500).send(`${err.name}: ${err.message}`);
        });
    });
    req.pipe(bb);
});

module.exports = router;
```

In the general failure case, how do I handle the scenario where the upload of 1 or more of x files being uploaded fails? Some uploads would have succeeded, some would have failed. However, in the `catch` clause I wouldn't know which ones have failed...

It would be good to be able to make this upload process somewhat *transactional* (i.e., either all uploads succeed, or none do). When errors happen, ideally I would be able to *"rollback"* the subset of successful uploads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it like this:

Push an object into uploads, with the data you need to retry, so:

```
uploads.push({ 
  fieldname, 
  filename, 
  mimeType,
  uploaded: S3.svc.upload({ Bucket: 'my-test-bucket', Key: filename, Body: stream })
    .promise()
    .then(() => true)
    .catch(() => false)
});

...

const failed = await 
  (Promise.all(uploads.map(async upload => ({...upload, uploaded: await upload.uploaded})))).then(u => u.filter(upload => !upload.uploaded))

const failedFiles = failed.join(', ')

console.log(`The following files failed to upload: ${failedFiles}`);
```

You need to make your event handlers `async` to use `await` inside them, so, for example:

```
bb.on('file', async (fieldname, stream, filename, encoding, mimeType) => {
```

Comment: A very interesting solution, thanks! Wouldn't the signature of the handler for the `file` event be dictated by the `busboy` module (I'm new enough to Javascript to be unsure of this)? See: [Busboy (special) events](https://www.npmjs.com/package/busboy#busboy-special-events)

Comment: True story, didn't think of that - it's not your API so you gotta roll with it!

Answer (score 2):

I finally went with the following code, which is an expansion of @JoshWulf's answer:

```
function handleUpload(req, res, bucket, key) {
    let bb = new Busboy({ headers: req.headers });
    const uploads = [];
    bb.on('file', (fieldname, stream, filename, encoding, mimeType) => {
        console.log(`Uploaded fieldname: ${fieldname}; filename: ${filename}, mimeType: ${mimeType}`);
        const params = { Bucket: bucket, Key: key, Body: stream, ContentType: mimeType };
        uploads.push({ filename, result: S3.svc.upload(params).promise().then(data => data).catch(err => err) });
    });
    bb.on('finish', async () => {
        const results = await Promise.all(uploads.map(async (upload) => ({ ...upload, result: await upload.result })));
        // handle success/failure with their respective objects
    });
    req.pipe(bb);
}
```

The difference here from @[Josh Wulf's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1758461/josh-wulf) answer is that in my upload promise I am returning the returned data object (if successful) and the returned error object (in case of failure) as-is. This then enables me to later use them as I need.

Comment: Nice solution! Good work. This will help someone in the future.